# Moving /home dir form sd card to USB drive on a Rasspberry pi 4

Tags: python, linux, python-3, memory, packages

I'm trying to run Insightface package on raspberry pi 4 after struggling to install all required packages namely cv2 and mxnet but when I exit python or run my program I get  “corrupted size vs. prev_size” which comes from the package mxnet. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628615/understanding-corrupted-size-vs-prev-size-glibc-error), I understand that I have low memory which doesn't let my program run correctly, I tried the solution from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move my home dir to a USB drive but it always gets stuck on the line:

```
sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: Moving the home directory will not free up memory only space on the SD card (disk space).

Comment: What's the ram size of your Raspberry Pi 4B? 1, 2 or 4 GB?

Comment: @Ingo its a 4 GB raspi

Comment: @Andyroo I'm trying to free up space to change swap siza

Comment: Why not move the swap onto the USB drive?

Comment: @Andyroo I created the swapfile on the USB and set it to 2048 but when I run free -h the swapsize is as much as it was when it was on the micro sd

Comment: Do not forget swap is only used when needed.  Not sure if you have to manually delete the old swap file or not.